# Button appears twice in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, button

Hellow guys,

I have a button appearing twice in Chrome but works fine in every other browsers (Opera, Edge, Firefox). Here's the image of the button:

[image: Button]

It's only a 1-file-upload button. You select a file and that's it. But on chrome, there's this "Choose File" button. In every other browser it's just the button behind it as intended so I'm sure it's not the source code that's wrong here.

Has this happened to any of you? What's the cause? How do I solve this?

I'm using the latest Chrome version (69.0.3497.100), tried it in incognito mode as well with no success. The problem happened at the last 3 or 4 chrome versions as well, it's not new.

Thank you for your time and answers!

Comment: Can you share your html? I guess that you are using an "input" tag, but just to be sure.

Comment: Sorry, I can not show it for some reasons, but you are right. That's the source of the problem?